# How to hide div element in android web view (Android Studio)

Tags: javascript, android-webview

**This is my code -**

```js
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://dsal.uchicago.edu/dictionaries/candrakanta/");

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if(webView.canGoBack())
        {
            webView.goBack();
        }
        else
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

****I want to hide this**-**

```
<div id="responsive_dico_info">
```

Please Help how to hide the above div element when the url load, I already tried many type of solution but not worked that is why I decided to post the question here. I think I will get the right answer here. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these options :

In your XML file:

```
android:visibility="gone" <-- hides
android:visibility="visible" <-- makes it visible
```

Or in java file:

```
textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);//makes it disappear
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//makes it visible again
```

Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/hide+elements+android